# Combinations of max vowels in first half of the word

Tags: permutations, combinations

I am trying to find the max combinations of ways in which a word can be rotated and maximum vowels are present in the first half of the string.

Eg GHIJ has 2 combinations IJGH and HIJG.

Similarly, another example. 
abecde
All possible combinations are : abecde eabecd deabec cdeabe ecdeab becdea
Relevant combinations: abecde eabecd deabec 
Max vowel count in the first half is 2. Hence the result should be 3

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Are the strings assumed to be of even length? If not, what characters are in the first half of a five-letter word?

Comment: Thomas Andrews : The strings are assumed to be even length

Comment: How about the question of if the word has an even number of vowels?  Do you count ties?  If not, then some words like `abababab` will regardless how they are rotated result in an equal number of vowels in the first half as the latter half.  The end result seems that since you are restricting yourself to a single word and its rotations that the result will depend on the word itself.

Comment: If your question is "among all words of size $2n$, what is the largest number of 'relevant combinations'" where 'relevant combinations' is as described above, then if you count ties then the answer is $2n$, using my example of `abababab` and similar.  If not, then you should be able to reason that at most one of the front half or back half can have strictly more vowels than the other and you can always rotate a word to swap which half is the front versus the back, that at most half of the rotations of the word will yield "relevant combinations" and so the maximum would be $n$, e.g. `aaaabbbb`

Comment: @JMoravitz I hope that it was clear that rotations can happen only in single direction,  after every rotation, your Character 1 become Character 2 and Character N become Character 1. I felt like ensuring this coz of the eg  of aaaabbbb

Comment: @JMoravitz yes we can reason that either of the sides contain more vowels , unless ofc vowels count is even,  then there is a chance that both the sides have equal vowels. But what i am really hoping for is a mathematical formula that derives the result based on reading the data. For eg,  I know the length,  total vowels and the distance between each vowel . Can this information be used to get the count of rotations where left weight of vowels is greater than right weight.

Comment: Replace vowels with $1$ and consonants with $0$. Everything else is irrelevant. Something I've noticed that might be helpful: any time you have two $1$s in your word which are exactly half the length of the word apart, drop them from the word, and the same for any time you have two $0$s half the word apart. This reduced word will satisfy your condition if and only if the original did.